# Separate Threads for UI and Logic - Android

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, vector

I want to create separate threads for implementing the core logic and updating the GUI.
Both threads should not share data with them directly. For this, i want to create a vector queue with synchronized get() and put() methods. 
Suppose if an onClick event happens in the GUI thread, it notifies the core thread that it received the OnClick event. So the core thread implements something and puts the result in the vector. At this point, the GUI thread is notified of the received result and it fetches it and updates the screen.
I cant figure out how to do this. Is there a way this could be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as you would in any other framework or environment.  The Android api offers you a lot of high level ways of handling multithreaded applications like you described (AsyncTask, Handler/Thread/Runnable, etc), but you can also wrap these in your own processing queue.  I've done that recently where I created a logical queue for processing, and when I push something to the queue, I run a method that checks my queue for items and processes them on a background thread.  You can notify the system when your processing is complete by sending broadcast intents and registering IntentFilters at the Activity level (don't forget to unregister) or you can implement your own listener interfaces the way the Android UI framework does with UI events on Views

At the heart of it though, however you wrap it, AsyncTask makes it really easy to call back and forth between background threads and the main UI thread.  onPreExecute, onProgressUpdated and onPostExecute all run on the UI thread and doInBackground runs in a background thread that is automatically created for you.  Doesn't get any easier than that

Comment: it's not as simple as "sample code".  My implementation of this is spread across several classes and several hundred lines of code.  I can describe it in pseudo code and tell you what objects from the framework I used to accomplish the task, but I don't have anything publicly available to spoon feed you your implementation.